# How to save billing info of guest user or auto register on checkout one page when user click on billing info continue buttion?

Tags: database, user

I want to save guest user info before placing order.
for example - if any user submitted billing info and click on continue button that time i have to save that info as user or in any other table.

purpose is that I want to see who was attempt to fill checkout form but its cancelled.

Comment: Dear Amit Thank you for your answer.
I think you dont understand my questions.
buddy my problem is that I have to register when a user as guest checkout and he filled info in billing form than click on continue of billing form, I have to save that information to user table or another table before place order.
I want to see  who was attempt to fill checkout form but its cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can do this by Magento [event Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) .

When magento is place an order it fire an event `checkout_submit_all_after`.By Using this you can save the details to other table.

**Event: Code at config.xml  is look like:**

```
 <events>
    <checkout_submit_all_after>
        <observers>
            <anything> <!-- <<< THIS NEEDS TO BE UNIQUE -->
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>yourmodelPrefix/observer</class>
                <method>InsertguestData</method>
            </anything><!-- <<< THIS NEEDS TO BE UNIQUE -->
        </observers>
    </checkout_submit_all_after>
</events>
```

you can get Order details using below code at Observer

$order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

Observer code:

```
   <?php
    class YourNamePsace_YourModule_Model_Observer
    {
        public function InsertguestData($observer)
        {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

         if($order->getCustomerIsGuest()==1){
          /* that means Customer has been checkout as guest **/

           }
        }
    }
```

and you can Check order is placed by `guest or register` by using field `customer_is_guest` fields

Comment: Dear Amit Thank you for your answer.
I think you dont understand my questions.
buddy my problem is that I have to register when a user as guest checkout and he filled info in billing form than click on continue of billing form, I have to save that information to user table or another table before place order.
I want to see  who was attempt to fill checkout form but its cancelled.